# Trying to use threading.Timer to run Flask app periodically

Tags: python, flask, timer, attributeerror

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, render_template
from News.News import News, news1_title, news1_topline

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(News, url_prefix="/News")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template(
    'index.html',
    news1_title_html = news1_title,
    news1_topline_html = news1_topline,
    )
    threading.Timer(30, index).start()

index()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I am trying to let the Flask app run every 30 seconds to refresh the parsed data from a news website for my flask server. The data is displayed through a html template (index.html). I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app' and there seems to be a problem with render_template.

I'm fairly new to this, sorry if this a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" >
```

in your HTML?

What does your app look like?

basic flask-app:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home ():
    return render_template("index.html")
# I'd go with debug for now:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

ou can do this several ways, I think:

1. using scheduler:

   ```
    from appscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

    sched = Scheduler()

    def func_for_getting_news:
        #get the news
    sched.add_interval_job(funcfor_gettin_news, minutes=1)
   ```
2. using threading:

import threading

```
def myApiCall(): 
    # your request lib here making an http call ... 
    # call myApi() again in 600 seconds/10min 
    threading.Timer(60, myApiCall).start() 
 
myApiCall()
```

Comment: The problem is, when the html is being refreshed like that, the variables which feed into it stay the same. 
Yes, that's how my flask app looks, additionally I load some blueprints which do the parsing work. It works fine without the timer. I added the code above.

Comment: How do you gather the data?

And why are you running index() ? After creating the route?

Comment: I get the data with requests.get(url) from the website, the request and parsing is happening inside the blueprint 'News'. I am not sure tbh, I thought I was creating the route '/' and then running the app index() to fill that route with my html template and stuff?

Comment: no need to run index() . 
Probably re-read the documentation? (God, I really hate such comments :-D )

Write a func. to get the news-data for you and use threading at the end?

Comment: Allright I think I figured it out. Thank you very much for your help!